# How to add a purchase note in admin email using Email Type 'Plain Text'? Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

When ordering online there is this part where you enter the Purchase Note or Order Note to the admin about something. This notes can be displayed when using the Email type **HTML** but when using the **Plain Text** it does not show in the admin notification email. How can I implement it so that it can show up?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hook in woocommerce/templates/emails/plain/admin-new-order.php

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

You can add piece of code into your functions.php and hook it to 'woocommerce_email_order_meta' that will fetch the note from order and display it. 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

Try something like this :

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_note_to_admin_new_order_plain', 20, 4);
function add_note_to_admin_new_order_plain($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email)
{
    if (!$sent_to_admin || !$plain_text) {
        return;
    }
    if ($order->get_customer_note()) {
        echo 'Customer note : ' . $order->get_customer_note();
    }
}
```

However, as i was testing this, i have noticed that default woocommerce theme shows the note by default, so you should check if the functionality is not unhooked or removed somewhere in your theme or plugin, can't help you with that as the customization can be done anywhere.

Comment: I can see that there is that hook in admin-new-order.php but still not showing up. can you help me more about that or how can I add that piece of code in the functions.php file?